# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to2}(x^3-2x-4)\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to2}(x^3-2x-4)\tan\dfrac{\pi x}{4}$$

I can't even determine what type of indeterminate form we have. It's $0\times\text{undefined}$. We can see that $2$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-2x-4$ and it factors as $(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)$. Additionally, when $x\to2$, $\tan\dfrac{\pi x}{4}\to\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2},$ which is not defined. How do we approach the problem and what's the intuition? I suppose somehow the limit $\lim_{f(x)\to0}\dfrac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)}=1$ may come in handy.

Comment: We can apply L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @Saunders the OP tagged "limits-without-lhopital".

Comment: You mentioned indeterminate forms in the question. If you do not want to use L'Hopital's Rule you should mention that in the question, not just the tags.

Comment: @geetha290krm, and how do you conclude that as I mentioned indeterminate forms, it's obvious I want to use L'Hopital's Rule considering the tags?

Comment: yinivem462 I think you misunderstood geetha's comment. He didn't conclude that. He only advised you not to rely only on the tag "limits-without-lhopital" to express you do not want to use L'Hopital's Rule, but to make it explicit in the text of your post.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=2+h.$ As $h\to0,$ using the [asymptotic notation $\sim$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) and the fact that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan t-\tan0}{t-0}=\tan'(0)=1:$
$$x^3-2x-4=10h+6h^2+h^3\sim 10h$$and
$$\tan\frac{\pi x}4=-\frac1{\tan\frac{\pi h}4}\sim-\frac4{\pi h}.$$
The limit of the product is therefore $-\frac{40}{\pi}.$

Comment: Well, perhaps it is useful clarify the asymptotic notation or at least reference so that the OP can check on Wikipedia. For the second asymptotic equivalence, fortunately we can still avoid using the L'Hôpital theorem. Anyway, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$ (x^3-2x-4) \tan(x\pi/4) = \frac{\sin(x\pi/4)(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)}{\cos(x\pi/4)}$$

Let $u = x-2$, then:

$$ = \frac{u\sin((u+2)\pi/4)((u+2)^2+2(u+2)+2)}{\cos((u+2)\pi/4)} $$

Where $\sin((u+2)\pi/4) = \cos(u\pi/4)$ and $\cos((u+2)\pi/4) = -\sin(u\pi/4)$ using the addition formulas for sine and cosine. So:

$$ \frac{u\cos(u\pi/4)((u+2)^2+2(u+2)+2)}{-\sin(u\pi/4)} = \frac{u\pi/4 \cos(u\pi/4)((u+2)^2+2(u+2)+2)}{-\pi/4\sin(u\pi/4)} =$$

$$ = -4/\pi \cdot \frac{u\pi/4}{\sin(u\pi/4)} \cdot \cos(u\pi/4) \cdot ((u+2)^2+2(u+2)+2)$$

We let $u \rightarrow 0$. First factor tends to $1$, second factor to $1$, last factor tends to $10$, the limit is therefore $-\frac{40}{\pi}$